# Laravel setting from database and accessible to all the Controllers and Views

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I am trying to load the Setting and Accessible to all the Controllers and views. Is there a nice way to do this.

Comment: To access settings in config file ? 
`config('app.key')`? Or from .env file with `env('KEY')`

Comment: we cannnot load from database wirh this aproach

Comment: Add a Settings model. You can then use that model to access any setting in the database anywhere.

Comment: @anyber I have settings modal but with this aproach i have to do lot of work ...like Settings::first() to get the setting object

Comment: If every controller extends the same controller (BaseController or just Controller) that you can edit, then add what you want into the `__construct()` function of that controller, and put them in class variables. Then you can use those class variables in any controller, or pass them along to a view.

Comment: @aynber can you show me little example?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you can modify the controller that all other controllers extend from, and add the variables to the __construct() function. For instance in my 5.3 project, all controllers extend App\Http\Controllers\Controller. In that controller, add (or update, if the function exists) something like this:

```
protected $settings; // Protected so child controllers can't modify it

public function __construct() {
    $this->settings = Settings::first();
}
```

You can do all sorts of logic here and set up any variables you want. Then in the child controllers, all you have to do to access them is use `$this->settings`, like

```
if($this->settings->my_setting == TRUE)
```

If you want to use it in a view, you'll have to pass it into the view. If you want to share it will all views, you can follow the [instructions here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views).